# dockerfile CMD - starting server on different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

I have 2 rails apps in docker which I want to start at the same time using `docker-compose up`, but I want to start each app on on different ports.

I have a different dockerfile for each app, with a single shared docker-compose.yml.  The docker-compose has 2 entries one for each app.

Here is an example of a `Dockerfile`, but for some reason its not accessible or its not starting on the specified port:

```
 Expose port to the Docker host, so we can access it
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 5000

# Configure an entry point, so we don't need to specify
# "bundle exec" for each of our commands.
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server”,”-p”, “5000”, "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Is there an issue with the syntax of `CMD`?

The docker-compose has the following snippet which suggests I am allowing port 5000 of the host access to port 5000 in the container, but it seems the server is not running on port 5000:

```
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
```

Anything missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it a problem with curling from the host? Or a problem with one container not  being able to talk the other other
2. Are you using host networking?
3. You don't need to use `EXPOSE` if you're specifying the port mappings in the docker-compose.yml
4. Are you absolutely sure your server is running on the specified host/port?

I can't see any problem with your `CMD`, but it's highly unusual to use both `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`.  I can see why you did it here, but I'd experiment with taking out the `ENTRYPOINT`.  Lastly, it would be helpful to demostrate that the server is indeed running on the host/port.  You can try

```
docker run -it "my/image" bash
> rails s -p 5000 -b 0.0.0.0 -d
> curl 0.0.0.0:5000 # should show your landing page if the server is indeed running on port 5000.
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as it lead me to the solution, which was embarassingly my docker-compose file had a CMD in it which needed the ports changed.